# Unable to map values of a Set into a model

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have the following model

```
case class TagPartitionsInfo (
                               year:Int,
                               month:Int
                             )

case class TagPartitions(tag:String,
                         partition_info:Set[TagPartitionsInfo])
```

The data in the `Cassandra` table is stored like follows:

```
tag        | partition_info
------------+--------------------------------------------------
 javascript | {{year: 2018, month: 1}, {year: 2018, month: 2}}
```

When I am querying the table, I am trying to create the `TagPartitions` as follows from the `ResultSet` but my code isn't compiling. The issue seem to be the way I am extracting `Set` from the row:

```
 TagPartitions(row.getString("tag"),row.getSet[TagPartitionsInfo]("partition_info",TagPartitionsInfo.getClass))
```

The error is `Cannot resolve symbol getSet`.

I also tried `row.getSet("partition_info",TagPartitionsInfo.getClass)` but then I see the error `Type mismatch, expected Set[TagPartitionsInfo], actual util.Set[Any]`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This worked. As I am using a `UDT`, I have to use `UDTType` and `UDTValue` to convert the `UDT` into my model

```
  val tag = row.getString("tag")
val partitionInfoType:UserType = session.getCluster().getMetadata.getKeyspace("codingjedi").getUserType("tag_partitions")

//create value
//the logic below assumes that there is only one element in the set
val partitionsInfo = 
row.getSet("partition_info",partitionInfoType.newValue().getClass)

println("tag is "+tag +" and partition info converted to UDTValue: "+partitionsInfo)
val udtValueScalaSet:Set[UDTValue] = partitionsInfo.asScala.toSet

//convert Set[UDTValue] = Set[TagPartitionsInfo]
val partitionInfoSet:Set[TagPartitionsInfo] = udtValueScalaSet.map(partition=>TagPartitionsInfo(partition.getLong("year"),partition.getLong("month")))
 return TagPartitions(tag,partitionInfoSet)
```